# Backbone.js `isNew` not returning `false` event after `model.save()`

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If you look in the Backbone.js docs, the description of `isNew()` is:

> Has this model been saved to the server yet? If the model does not yet have an id, it is considered to be new.

But no matter what I do, `isNew` always returns `true`.

As you can see below, I've created a new model (it even has a `cid`), added it to a collection, run a `fetch()` on the collection, and despite all that, `isNew` still returns `true` for the model. The `save` function is hitting a RESTful API that I've got running and the record is being successfully saved to the DB.

```
a = new TodoModel({title: 'hi there'});

> s {cid: "c14", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}

a.save();

> Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}

b = new TodoCollection();

> s {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}

b.add(a);

> s {cid: "c14", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}

b.fetch();

> Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}

a.isNew();

> true
```

So, how do I get `isNew` to return false?

Comment: Are you returning a unique ID from the server? It is the ID that decides if something is 'new' by default.

Answer (score 0):

Add your own `isNew` to your model.  Maybe you want `cid` to be the thing that makes it new, or perhaps you have your own flag you set to false when you save it.   Here's what I have done in the past.

```
isNew: function () {
    return this.id > 0 ? false : true;
}
```